# Create a class specifically for retrieving an image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a method of retrieving an image from the gallery that works perfectly fine for me.  My issue is, I use it in three separate activities and feel that I should make a class that can be called to get the image.

This is my code:

```
private void getImage () {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mRLMenuParams.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mRLImageParams.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    bmSelectedImage = null;

    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imSelectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_image);
            imSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
            Bitmap bmImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
            bmSelectedImage = bmImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When I try to put this in its own class, i can't get it to work, even when passing the Context.  It seems that I would need to make it an activity, and if so, I don't see the point in separating it.  Am I missing something that will allow me to put this in its own class and return the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the method onActivityResult which comes from Activity. Maybe have a class method to do the code you have inside onActivityResult. Change your class to contain two separate methods, since if your separate class contains onActivity it won't work unless it's an activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html